# Collection of ObservableCollections of different types

Tags: c#, nested, observablecollection, covariance

I'm working on a problem where I have two nested TabControls. Both should bind to a collection.
The parent tab control should bind to a collection called devices.
This devices-collection should contain several ObservableCollections of different types which should be displayed in a different way in the ContentTemplate.

I tried something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<CellPhone> CellPhones { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Watch> Watches { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>> Devices { get; set; }
```

`Watch` and `CellPhone` inherit from `DeviceItem`.

I tried the following:

```
CellPhones = new ObservableCollection<CellPhone>();
Watches = new ObservableCollection<Watch>();
Devices = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>>();
Devices.Add(CellPhones); // it fails here...
```

It says:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CellPhone>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>'
```

I do understand this error message, but I haven't found a workaround.

I read about covariance in c#, but apparently that's not working for ObservableCollections.

Do you have another idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Does your peropty "Devices" always contain the two collections, one of Watches and one of CellPhones? Or shall Devices contain more than those 2 collection instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a separate class `Device`

```
public class Device
{

    public Device(String arg_DeviceName)
    {
        DeviceName = arg_DeviceName;
    }


    public String DeviceName { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<DeviceItem> Items
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

And than I solved it like this:

```
public Device CellPhones{ get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<DeviceItem> CellPhoneItems
{
    get; set;
}

public Device Watches { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<DeviceItem> WatchItems
{
    get; set;
}

public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices
{
    get; set;
}



CellPhones = new Device("Cells");
CellPhoneItems = new ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>();
Watches = new Device("Watch");
WatchItems = new ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>();
CellPhones.Items = CellPhoneItems;
Watches.Items = WatchItems;
Devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();
Devices.Add(CellPhones);
Devices.Add(Watches);
```

With this I can bind to the `Items`-Property of the `Device`-class.

Thank you HimBromBeere. You opened my eyes and pushed me towards the solution.

Answer (score 2):

A `List<Derived>` simply is not a `List<Base>`, even if a `Derived` is a `Base`. The same applies to an `ObservableCollection`. In other words: if this were allowed, you could put **both**, `List<CellPhone>` and `List<Watch>` into your list at the same time. How would any user know what items he actually has in his list:

```
var a = Devices[0]; // what type has a here? compiler can´t infer that type
```

Why not simply make `Watches` and `CellPhones` an `ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>` in the first place:

```
public ObservableCollection<DeviceItem> CellPhones { get; set; }    
public ObservableCollection<DeviceItem> Watches { get; set; }    
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DeviceItem>> Devices { get; set; }
```

Now you can easily do this:

```
Devices.Add(CellPhones);
Devices.Add(Watches);
```

Comment: Technically that worked. But I wasn't able to bind the inner collection to a WPF TabControl.
I write another answer with my solution now.

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing in Xamarin.Forms is using Interfaces.

So, imaging I have a class with name `Student` and also a class with name `Teacher`.

I know both of them have some properties in common e.g `DateOfBirth` so I have an interface called: `ISchoolMember` that has:

```
DateTime? DateOfBirth {get; set;}
```

If both `Student` and `Teacher` implement my `ISchoolMember` interface, I can now create an `ObservableCollection` (or even better, `ObservableRangeCollection`) of type `ISchoolMember` so in this way I can have `Student`, `Teacher` or any other type that implements my interface in it.

When I need Students only I can use `OfType<Student>()` in a LINQ query.